# How forward and reverse DNS works

Tags: dns

What I understand about how DNS works is like this: first let's assume `mydomain.com` has the IP address `12.34.56.78`. Now when I put the url mydomain.com in the browser, the browser sends a dns lookup to its local dns server, asking, hey, do you know the ip address for mydomain.com. If the local dns server does not know about it, it will ask the parent dns servers, if the parent also does not know, then it keeps asking all the way up until the root  dns server. The root dns server will ask some server in charge of the `.com` tld. The dns server in charge of the `.com` will have knowledge about `mydomain.com` because `mydomain.com` is the `.com` family. Then the answer will be returned back to the initial asker. Also the answer quite likely will be cached in the dns servers involved in the asking process. Would anyone correct my understanding if it is wrong.

So my real question is about how reverse dns lookup works. Let's say if I want to find out what domain name is for the ip `12.34.56.78`. I run the command `dig -x 12.34.56.78`. If my local dns server does not know the answer, which server does it further ask? Is it `12.in-addr.arpa.`, or `34.12.in-addr.arpa.`? If this is the case, are these names like `12.in-addr.arpa.` valid domain names? And where should they be deployed so that the reverse lookup requests will know whom to ask?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How a reverse DNS lookup is accomplished:

- The DNS resolver reverses the IP, and adds it to ".in-addr.arpa" (or ".ip6.arpa" for IPv6 lookups), turning 192.0.2.25 into 25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
- The DNS resolver then looks up the PTR record for 25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.

  - The DNS resolver asks the root servers for the PTR record for 25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
  - The root servers refer the DNS resolver to the DNS servers in charge of the Class A range (192.in-addr.arpa, which covers all IPs that begin with 192).
  - In almost all cases, the root servers will refer the DNS resolver to a "RIR" ("Regional Internet Registry"). These are the organizations that allocate IPs. In general, ARIN handles North American IPs, APNIC handles Asian-Pacific IPs, and RIPE handles European IPs.
  - The DNS resolver will ask the ARIN DNS servers for the PTR record for 25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
  - The ARIN DNS servers will refer the DNS resolver to the DNS servers of the organization that was originally given the IP range. These are usually the DNS servers of your ISP, or their bandwidth provider.
  - The DNS resolver will ask the ISP's DNS servers for the PTR record for 25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
  - The ISP's DNS servers will refer the DNS resolver to the organization's DNS servers.
  - The DNS resolver will ask the organization's DNS servers for the PTR record for 25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.
  - The organization's DNS servers will respond with "host.example.com".

Source [here](http://www.dnsstuff.com/docs/ptr/).

Comment: WOW @Shoikana, it's very clear. Thank you so much. So can all of the things be done with bind9 in a completely isolated lab? Let's say I have a completely isolated lab, with as many servers as needed. Can I make all the forward and reverse lookup processes done with only bind9? Or the RIR still uses any private protocols to talk to the ISPs?

Comment: One nuance that is missing from the original answer is that a typical desktop or laptop does not run a Recursive DNS server.  It only has a resolver that can contact your ISP's or Organization's Recursive DNS server.  That DNS Server may be pre-configured to answer PTR queries for *.in-addr.arpa hostnames that fall within the orgination's IP space (especially if it is not globally routable IP space).  Only if that server does not have the answer, it will perform the above-mentioned resolution.  (Assuming it has no cached answers already.)